# How to merge header columns in jsf h:dataTable in jsf-version 1.1?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-1.2

I have to merge columns of the header. And I have two rows of headers to be shown in jsf dataTable.
So I used some thing of this kind in the beginning of the dataTable. This worked fine.But this is making rendered condition get ignored on the t:column attribute.(All the columns irrespective of the rendered attribute). I tried placing rendered attribute inside t:column on h:outputText tag but in vain.

```
<t:dataTable var="myvo" value=...............................>
<f:facet name="header">
<t:panelGroup><f:verbatim escape="false"> 
  <TR>   
<TH colspan="1" align="center" class="tableHeader">Title</TH>   
<TH colspan="1" align="center" class="tableHeader">myheader1</TH>   
<TH colspan="1" align="center" class="tableHeader">myheader2</TH>   
 </TR>   
</f:verbatim>
</t:panelGroup>   
</f:facet> 

<t:column rendered="#{!myvo.myflag}">
<f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Internal Header1"/></f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{myvo.myContent1}" styleClass="BodyFont" /></t:column>
<t:column rendered="#{myvo.myflag}">
<f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Internal Header2"/></f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{myvo.myContent2}" styleClass="BodyFont" /></t:column>
</t:column>
<t:column rendered="#{!myvo.myflag}">
<f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Internal Header3"/></f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{myvo.myContent3}" styleClass="BodyFont" /></t:column>
</t:column>
<t:column rendered="#{myvo.myflag}">
<f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Internal Header4"/></f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{myvo.myContent4}" styleClass="BodyFont" /></t:column>
</t:column>
<t:column rendered="#{!myvo.myflag}">
<f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Internal Header5"/></f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{myvo.myContent5}" styleClass="BodyFont" /></t:column>
</t:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error. The variable I used in rendered condition is wrong(different from the one defined in my Java  Bean class). But I did not understand why it is not throwing any error on the jsp page.